# Occasional exception org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, hibernate, high-load

**Issue:**
In our web application under high load sometimes, when there are two simultaneous Hibernate queries in different threads (in same millisecond), we have two exceptions (in both threads): "*org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property*" on different entities and different properties.
It looks like two queries have exchanged their property mappings for some reason so *AbstractPropertyMapping* class can't find required property in mappings of other query's entity and raises *QueryException*. Each entity is used only in one thread.

**Environment:**

- Apache Tomcat 7
- Spring 4.0.6
- Hibernate 4.3.6.Final

**Configuration:**

```
<!-- Configuration -->

...
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionTemplate" class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />       
        <property name="packagesToScan">            
            <list>                
              <value>com.delta.invest.domain</value>                             
            </list>        
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>

                <!-- For debuging purposes -->
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>

                <!-- @see: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCoreMigrationGuide36 -->
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary">false</prop>

                <!-- For batch inserts -->
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.order_inserts">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</prop>             
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data">true</prop>
                <!-- prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop-->

                <!-- Second-level cache -->
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">ehcache.xml</prop>

                <!-- Autoregister Joda types -->
                <prop key="jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes">true</prop>

                <!-- Turn off domain classes validation -->
                <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>

                <!-- Set TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED isolation level -->
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.isolation">2</prop>



            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

...
```

**Exception in first thread:**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: accountTo of: com.delta.invest.domain.entity.core.A
ccountEntry
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1978)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.EntityCriteriaInfoProvider.getType(EntityCriteriaInfoProvider.java:57)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getPathInfo(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:245)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.createCriteriaEntityNameMap(CriteriaQueryTranslator.jav
a:229)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.<init>(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.<init>(CriteriaLoader.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1663)
        at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
        at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:402)
        at com.delta.invest.dao.kernel.SelectionDAOImpl.getCount(SelectionDAOImpl.java:216)
        at com.delta.invest.service.SelectionServiceImpl.getRowCountByCriteria(SelectionServiceImpl.java:406)
        at com.delta.invest.service.SelectionServiceImpl.getSize(SelectionServiceImpl.java:185)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor422.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:
190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterce
ptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspec
tSupport.java:262)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy99.getSize(Unknown Source)
        at com.delta.invest.service.PageSelectionServiceImpl.getSize(PageSelectionServiceImpl.java:60)
        at com.delta.invest.paging.PagingCollection.size(PagingCollection.java:64)
        at com.delta.invest.ws.document.DocumentWebServiceImpl.getDocumentsHistoryForOperator(DocumentWebServiceImpl.jav
a:344)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:
190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterce
ptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspec
tSupport.java:262)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy99.getSize(Unknown Source)
        at com.delta.invest.service.PageSelectionServiceImpl.getSize(PageSelectionServiceImpl.java:60)
        at com.delta.invest.paging.PagingCollection.size(PagingCollection.java:64)
        at com.delta.invest.ws.document.DocumentWebServiceImpl.getDocumentsHistoryForOperator(DocumentWebServiceImpl.jav
a:344)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:
190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.
java:122)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:73)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy220.getDocumentsHistoryForOperator(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
        ... 91 more
```

**Exception in second thread:**

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: accountTo of: com.delta.invest.domain.entity.core.AccountEntry
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1978)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.EntityCriteriaInfoProvider.getType(EntityCriteriaInfoProvider.java:57)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getPathInfo(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:245)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.createCriteriaEntityNameMap(CriteriaQueryTranslator.jav
a:229)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.<init>(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.<init>(CriteriaLoader.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1663)
        at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
        at com.delta.invest.dao.kernel.SelectionDAOImpl.list(SelectionDAOImpl.java:159)
        at com.delta.invest.service.SelectionServiceImpl.getAll(SelectionServiceImpl.java:358)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor524.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:
190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterce
ptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspec
tSupport.java:262)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy99.getAll(Unknown Source)
        at com.delta.invest.service.TransactionServiceImpl.getLinkedAccountEntries(TransactionServiceImpl.java:1479)
        at com.delta.invest.service.TransactionServiceImpl.executeTransaction(TransactionServiceImpl.java:743)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor713.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:
190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInte
rceptor.java:64)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterce
ptor.java:98)       
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspec
tSupport.java:262)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.executeTransaction(Unknown Source)
        at com.delta.invest.processing.operation.CreateTransactionOperation.commitTransaction(CreateTransactionOperation
.java:82)
        at com.delta.invest.processing.operation.CreateTransactionOperation.execute(CreateTransactionOperation.java:50)
        at com.delta.invest.processing.DocumentLifecycleManagerImpl.executeDocumentaryOperations(DocumentLifecycleManage
rImpl.java:181)
        at com.delta.invest.processing.DocumentLifecycleManagerImpl.process(DocumentLifecycleManagerImpl.java:110)
        at com.delta.invest.processing.DocumentLifecycleManagerImpl.process(DocumentLifecycleManagerImpl.java:188)
        at com.delta.invest.service.DocumentServiceImpl.process(DocumentServiceImpl.java:229)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor729.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:
190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInte
rceptor.java:64)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterce
ptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspec
tSupport.java:262)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy116.process(Unknown Source)
        at com.delta.invest.service.remote.RemoteSupportServiceImpl.process(RemoteSupportServiceImpl.ja
va:367)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor709.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:
190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor.invoke(RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor
.java:78)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy260.process(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor709.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.caucho.hessian.server.HessianSkeleton.invoke(HessianSkeleton.java:306)
        at com.caucho.hessian.server.HessianSkeleton.invoke(HessianSkeleton.java:221)
        at org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianExporter.doInvoke(HessianExporter.java:223)
        at org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianExporter.invoke(HessianExporter.java:138)
        at org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianServiceExporter.handleRequest(HessianServiceExporter.java:66)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.j
ava:152)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at ch.qos.logback.access.servlet.TeeFilter.doFilter(TeeFilter.java:55)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:202)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:180)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.
java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityIntercepto
r.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:1
13)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticatio
nFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextH
olderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:4
5)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(Abs
tractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:94)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebA
syncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistence
Filter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Source code:**

```
@Repository(value="selectionDAO")
public class SelectionDAOImpl implements SelectionDAO
{

    ...

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;  

    ...
    public <Entity> List<Entity> list( Class<Entity> entityClass, final DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria,
                                     final int firstResult, final int maxResults )
    {

        Criteria criteria = detachedCriteria.getExecutableCriteria(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession());
        if ( firstResult > 0 ) { criteria.setFirstResult( firstResult ); }
        if ( maxResults > 0 ) { criteria.setMaxResults( maxResults ); }

        return (List<Entity>) criteria.list();
    }

    public Long getCount( final DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria )
    {
        return (Long) detachedCriteria.getExecutableCriteria(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).setProjection( Projections.rowCount() ).uniqueResult();
    }

    ...
}
```

How can I prevent this exception?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Concurrency problems are usually hard to debug. It may be a configuration mistake, but if it isn't, without the client's hibernation calls, I don't think there is a likely chance in finding the problem.

Comment: How do you instantiate your Hibernate sessions ? Are you sure that each requests (thread) get a different instance ?

Comment: You need to add the stacktrace too.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x If there is possibility of a configuration mistake do you have any thoughts on what kind of mistake it could be?

Comment: Stéphane, using Spring @Transactional  annotation. As far as I know, in case of HibernateTransactionManager Spring should put Session in Thread Local context, so each thread should have different instance. I'll check it.

Comment: Maybe you crated `DetachedCriteria` for the wrong entity than the one you're expecting.

Comment: @VladMihalcea in that case I would have constant exceptions, not occasional.

Comment: So there are different Session instances. Other exception I got under close circumstances is: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getWhereCondition(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:417)